# Why can't email clients create rules for moving dates like "yesterday"?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, email-client

I've never seen an email client that I could easily create a rule to do something like "Move messages from *yesterday* to a folder?" Is there some esoteric reason why this would be difficult? I know I can easily create rules around specific dates, but that isn't the same thing by a long shot; am I missing something? In Outlook 2010 I can create search folders that do sort of this type of thing, but you can't create rules around a search folder... seems like either I am missing something major, or this is terribly short-sided.

Comment: I don't think there is a real answer for this.  Anything is possible in code.  Why developers havent

Comment: A shame this is closed; I take it to mean a client which provides this possibility without any scripting/programming, i.e. just by filling in GUI dialogues. Some cases (deletion) are handled in http://superuser.com/questions/549565/deleting-emails-from-a-sender-after-x-days?noredirect=1&lq=1 and http://superuser.com/questions/1105603/how-to-set-time-based-rules-in-outlook/1106707#1106707

Comment: If you want to move after _n_ days, you could, as a compromise, copy immediately and delete after _n_ days, as explained in the answers to the questions referred to in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you can do this with Outlook + VBA script. In Thunderbird, there is a filter that selects emails by their age (in days) and also a filter action that lets you move filtered messages to a specified folder.

These are just the 2 most popular email clients, but this is definitely possible with other clients as well.

Comment: Ah my mistake on Thunderbird... I rarely use it, but I thought I remembered it not having the ability.

Doesn't it seem odd thought that you would have to go through the trouble of scripting for this functionality in Outlook?

Comment: @Morgan: Sorta. It's not a super common functionality (you can't do it with Gmail; not sure about Live or Yahoo! mail), but it's definitely a useful filter to have. If I had it my way, it'd be on all clients. But then if I had it my way, all clients would probably get pretty bloated. =P

Answer (score 1):

Standard rule for The Bat! For any *exact or approximate* age ("Yesterday" here is "from 2 to 1 days old")

[image]