# How to set time based rules in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-client, email-filter, mail-rule

My employer sends out lots of internal marketing and "aren't we great" emails that I don't read. I currently have a rule which moves the emails sent by the worst offenders to a CompanyName Spam folder in Outlook 2010.

Is there a way to have the emails delete after a period of time, lets say 30 days, without me having to do this manually? Ideally, I'd like a single rule to say:
IF it's from joe.bloggs@CompanyName.com
MOVE to CompanyName Spam
AND after 30 days, move to deleted items folder.

I can make a rule to find emails within a particular absolute date range, but not a rolling relative date range (such as today - 30).

To make this even more complicated, if this could be done without VBA, that would be greatly appreciated (as I'm slow at using VBA and encoding)

Thanks,

Comment: The given duplicate is a duplicate of the question in the body of this post, but not of the title, which is more general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click on your 'spam' folder and select Properties, then go to AutoArchive, you should be able to archive emails older than n-days, then select to delete the emails instead of archiving them.

Answer (score 3):

> ### [Create a rule to delete mail after a number of days](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/create-rule-to-expire-mail-after-a-number-of-days/)
>
> You can combine a Rules Wizard rule with the AutoArchive feature of
>   Microsoft Outlook to automatically delete messages as they age. There
>   are two ways you can do this:
>
> 1. Create a rule that moves messages meeting certain criteria to a
>      folder. Configure the folder's Archive setting to delete messages.
> 2. Setting an expire date on messages as they arrive.
>
> In either case, AutoArchive will delete the messages for you once
>       they age.
>
> If you need help configuring autoarchive settings, watch the tutorial:
>   [Configuring AutoArchive settings in Microsoft
>   Outlook.](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/archive-outlook/using-outlooks-autoarchive-feature/)
>
> ### Move messages to a new folder
>
> 1. Create a rule that moves messages to a folder.
> 2. Switch to this folder, then right click on the folder and choose
>      **Properties**.
> 3. On the **AutoArchive** tab, choose how often to clean out items and
>      whether they should be archived or deleted.
>
> [image]
>
> ### Set an expiration date on the messages
>
> Follow these steps to create a run a script rule to add an expire date
>   and then configure AutoArchive to delete the messages.
>
> When a message is expired it's displayed in the message list in a gray
>   strikethrough font.
>
> Check [macro security
>   settings](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/).
>   Macro security should be set to Low during testing. Once you verify
>   the macro works, you can use [SelfCert to sign the
>   macro](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/#selfcert),
>   at which point you will change the security setting to allow signed
>   macros only.
>
> In Outlook 2010 and 2013, click **File**, **Options**, **Trust Center**. Click the
>   **Trust Center Settings** button then **Macro Security**. Select the bottom
>   option for Low security. In Outlook 2007, look on the **Tools** menu for
>   **Trust Center**, then **Macro Security**. In older versions of Outlook, go to
>   **Tools**, **Macros**, **Macro Security**.
>
> 1. Press **Alt+F11** to open the VBA Editor.
> 2. Right click on **Project1** and choose **Insert** > **Module**
> 3. Add the macro below to the new module.
> 4. Create a rule, selecting **Run a Script** as the action. If you set all
>      of the conditions in the rule, you can delete the If...Then and End
>      If lines.
> 5. Create a filter for your view that hides expired messages between
>      AutoArchive runs.
>
> [image]
>
> 6. Configure **AutoArchive** to delete expired messages
>
> [image]
>
> The macro will set the message to expire in 1 day. You can use .5 to
>   expire the message after 12 hours.
>
> If you use conditions in the rule to filter the messages, you can
>   remove the If...Then and End If lines from the code.
>
> ```
> Sub SetExpire(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
>
> If Left(LCase(Item.Subject), 7) = "weather" Then
>     Item.ExpiryTime = Now + 1
>     Item.Save
> End If
>
> End Sub
> ```
>
> <sub>[source](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/create-rule-to-expire-mail-after-a-number-of-days/)</sub>